# Prevent page auto-scroll in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MCV4 application (developed in visual studio 2012 using C#) and whenever I click a link (note 90% of my links are HTML.ActionLink) the page scroll position automatically resets to the top of the page. This is very frustrating because the layout of the page isn't being reloaded, it's only the rendered view. I've tried

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
            return false;
});
```

but all this does is stop my links from working altogether.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: how it should work? are you using links for `ajax` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before your return.

Comment: I'm pretty certain (99%) will indeed fix the problem! [See docs for event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) "If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered." The next thing you want to do, is add a class to the links you want to prevent the default behaviour for. Instead of $('a').etc. you can change it to your class variant, like: $('a.theHtmlClass').etc..

Comment: Tried that as well, still failed. I don't know how to add a class to an HTML.ActionLink, unfortunately.